# Apple review objection Invalid directory name for Plugins folder (Child Browser Cordova)

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, appstore-approval

I recently published my Worklight based App on Apple Store. Now i have received an email from Apple that says:

> **Invalid Directory Name** - Your app contains a directory name that is already reserved: '**Plugins**'. You must rename this directory.

In this App I am using Child browser plugin which is using plugin directory.

Now if i rename this "Plugins" folder then i have to do many changes, i hope it should be possible.

Kindly suggest me or guide me, what areas i must look into when editing this plugin.

- Native code that comes along with childbrowser plugin
- JS code

I am using this child browser plugin in my project.
https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

Comment: You may also want to look at InAppBrowser - you may be able to avoid the use of ChildBrowser altogether as it is built into Cordova and doesn't require an extra plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few steps required to fix in XCode.

- Right Click on the plugins folder and select Show in Finder.
- Change the directory name plugins with CBPlugin.
- Now back to XCode and click to change name Plugins directory with CBPlugin.

if these plugins files are referenced or copied elsewhere in project then delete the file from XCode (Not from CBPlugin folder) and reference it again.

[image]

and finally add these .h and .m files again into Compile Sources to make this plugin available for app in XCode.

[Integrate ChildBrowser into Worklight App (IOS Version)](http://saifo.blogspot.com/2013/04/integrate-childbrowser-into-worklight.html)

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Saifuddin, let me try this.