# Invalid Directory Name - Your app contains a directory name that is already reserved

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just submitted my app for review and was then emailed this error message:

`Invalid Directory Name - Your app contains a directory name that is already reserved: 'Frameworks'. You must rename this directory.`

Anyone have experience with this?

edit for a little more info: The only thing I have changed recently which may have caused this is to use Cocoapods.  I'm opening and compiling from the xcworkspace.  I do notice that a library called 'QuickDialogs' which I use had a Group called 'Frameworks' which I renamed.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates a "`Frameworks`" directory? What are you trying to do with it?  Can you name it to something else?  "`Frameworks`" is meant for shared & dynamic libraries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932785/apple-review-objection-invalid-directory-name-for-plugins-folder-child-browser

Comment: @NitinGohel - I looked but was not able to find a Frameworks directory.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann As far as I can tell I am not creating a 'Frameworks' directory.  I have been able to release several version of the app to date without a problem.  Just wondering if this was some sort of weird bug or something.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with cocoapods...what did you do?

Comment: and so what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. find and open `${YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT}/Pods/Pods-resources.sh`
2. search `${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}` and replace with `${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}`
3. clean your project and delete derived Data(organizer-projects)
4. achive your application again

I met this problem when I add extra frameworks by cocoapods. App store's response told me that there was a directory named `Frameworks`, which is reserved.
This folder is created at `Copy Pods Resources` step in `Build Phases`,

Comment: That worked for me too. Well, at least the app is in "Waiting for review" status now.

Comment: Sounds like this helped several people.  Accepting as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that using ShareKit with Cocoapods was adding a Frameworks to my binary. That's why I substituted:

```
pod "ShareKit"
```

with:

```
pod "ShareKit/Facebook"
pod "ShareKit/Twitter"
pod "ShareKit/GooglePlus"
```

as I only use these services.

In order to see the folder created go to your binary and see the contents of the archive generated in the Applications folder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: btw this worked for me if only added sharekit/facebook and sharekit/twitter.. google plus adds the frameworks directory

Comment: I suppose that is depending on the version that we are using. I hope in the next version they solve this issue.